# Display JSON data from unlabeled field with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I am pretty new to getting data from an API and formatting json, I have been making some big progress however I hit a snag.

- I am able to get the data from the API
- I am able to wait to process the data with a callback
- I am able to choose the nested section of data
- I am able to display the data

Where I am stuck: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question to Google but I can't seem to find anything that will allow me to only return the 5th item "NY".

When I display the items from `short_name` I get everything:

- 11776
- Port Jefferson Station
- Brookhaven
- Suffolk County
- NY
- US

Without a name for the sections how can I display just the 5th item?
- NY

```js
var the_state = {  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "address_components":[  
            {  
               "long_name":"11776",
               "short_name":"11776",
               "types":[  
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Port Jefferson Station",
               "short_name":"Port Jefferson Station",
               "types":[  
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Brookhaven",
               "short_name":"Brookhaven",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_3",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Suffolk County",
               "short_name":"Suffolk County",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"New York",
               "short_name":"NY",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[  
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776, USA",
         "geometry":{  
            "bounds":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":40.937698,
                  "lng":-73.008309
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":40.888503,
                  "lng":-73.0763651
               }
            },
            "location":{  
               "lat":40.90860139999999,
               "lng":-73.0464309
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":40.937698,
                  "lng":-73.008309
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":40.888503,
                  "lng":-73.0763651
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"ChIJJ9atd-BA6IkRfXg_wE1Klkg",
         "postcode_localities":[  
            "PORT JEFF STA",
            "Port Jefferson Station"
         ],
         "types":[  
            "postal_code"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
};
var state_output = $(".current-state");

$(the_state.results).each(function(k, results){    
  $(results.address_components).each(function(index, address_component) {
   state_output.append("<li>" + address_component.short_name + "</li>");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="current-state"></ol>
```

Comment: Are you sure the item you want will always be the 5th element of the array? It seems like you should actually be checking the `types` array for the type name you want.

Comment: I'm am not 100% sure. I just did a few tests, you are right it isn't always the 5th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you should be relying on the address components being in a specific order, you should look for the `administrative_area_level_1` type.

Also, you should use `$.each()` to loop over arrays. `$(variable).each()` is for looping over jQuery collections.

```js
var the_state = {
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
        "long_name": "11776",
        "short_name": "11776",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Port Jefferson Station",
        "short_name": "Port Jefferson Station",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Brookhaven",
        "short_name": "Brookhaven",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_3",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Suffolk County",
        "short_name": "Suffolk County",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "New York",
        "short_name": "NY",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "United States",
        "short_name": "US",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776, USA",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.937698,
          "lng": -73.008309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.888503,
          "lng": -73.0763651
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.90860139999999,
        "lng": -73.0464309
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.937698,
          "lng": -73.008309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.888503,
          "lng": -73.0763651
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJJ9atd-BA6IkRfXg_wE1Klkg",
    "postcode_localities": [
      "PORT JEFF STA",
      "Port Jefferson Station"
    ],
    "types": [
      "postal_code"
    ]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
};
var state_output = $(".current-state");

$.each(the_state.results, function(k, results) {
  $.each(results.address_components, function(index, address_component) {
    if (address_component.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") != -1) {
      state_output.append("<li>" + address_component.short_name + "</li>");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="current-state"></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using the `index` param and remember to return `false` to stop the `each` loop.

```js
var the_state = {
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
        "long_name": "11776",
        "short_name": "11776",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Port Jefferson Station",
        "short_name": "Port Jefferson Station",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Brookhaven",
        "short_name": "Brookhaven",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_3",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Suffolk County",
        "short_name": "Suffolk County",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "New York",
        "short_name": "NY",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "United States",
        "short_name": "US",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Port Jefferson Station, NY 11776, USA",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.937698,
          "lng": -73.008309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.888503,
          "lng": -73.0763651
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.90860139999999,
        "lng": -73.0464309
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.937698,
          "lng": -73.008309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.888503,
          "lng": -73.0763651
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJJ9atd-BA6IkRfXg_wE1Klkg",
    "postcode_localities": [
      "PORT JEFF STA",
      "Port Jefferson Station"
    ],
    "types": [
      "postal_code"
    ]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
};
var state_output = $(".current-state");

$(the_state.results).each(function(k, results) {
  state_output.append("<li>" + results.address_components[4].short_name + "</li>");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="current-state"></ol>
```

Comment: Why use a loop to access a specific index? Just use `results.address_components[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(the_state.results).each(function(k, results){    
  $(results.address_components).each(function(index, address_component) {
   if(index === 4) {
      state_output.append("<li>" + address_component.short_name + "</li>");
   }
  })
})
```

Just check the index to see if it's the 5th element in the array. :) Hope it helps. *code untested*.

Comment: You could also check if the "type" under the element is of "administrative_area_level_1" which is the state.

Comment: Wow, it seems so obvious now... Thank you!!

Comment: Why use a loop to get to a specific index? Just access it with `[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want parsing the JSON into Javascript. Something like this:

```
    var the_state = {
                  "long_name":"New York",
                  "short_name":"NY",
    };
```

and after

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(the_state);
document.write(parsedJSON .long_name + ' ' + parsedJSON .short_name);
```

Comment: `the_state` isn't JSON, it's an object. You shouldn't call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: He's getting the data from an API, he can't change the structure of it like this. He wants to get the name from a specific element of the array.

Comment: You are right. I apologized, I was misunderstood about the question because JSON.parse() converts JSON String to a JSON object. So if it is an object, I couldn't do that. +1 for correct me. Thank you.